# How to add floating values to a d3 axis? The values always round

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making a chart in which I need the ticks to be a float. For some reason, the values are being rounded. Could anyone explain why?

```
const key = d3.scaleLinear() 
    .domain([2.8, 12.8])
    .range([0, 300]);

    svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(150, 638)')
    .call(d3.axisBottom(key)
    .ticks(10)
    .tickFormat(d3.format('.1f')));
```

This is the output:

[image: I want the first tick to be 2.8]

I want the first tick to be 2.8.
Thank you.

Comment: ‘’’.ticks(11).tickValues((ti,i) => 2.8 + i)’’’

Comment: As for the why, D3 is designed to have scales that have roundish numbers  by default as opposed to unround numbers.